# Downvoting when User hearts are already empty

Tags: stack-egg

Choosing Downvote when User hearts are empty, will add to Quality and doesn't immediately mark Users as red (needing attention). Is there any downside to boosting Quality in this way, or would it be a better choice than first raising the User hearts (thru upvotes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downvote does not reduce the User count (unlike Close, it drains 1-2 hearts immediately) but instead makes User Count drain faster. (around X1.5-2.5.) This lasts for 1-2 hearts. That's why Close is worse on questions than Downvote is bad on Users. (Close drains 1-2 hearts immediately while Downvote does it slowly)

Comment: Good info, but it doesn't answer my question re. downvoting when User count is 0

Comment: It does. If you keep it this way, it will turn from 0 hearts to red quicker than normal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code is now out on [GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/stackegg) and the values can go into the negatives (but you won't see it). That's how stats get red and need attention when they reach a certain negative value (below -1.5)

```
public IEnumerable<StackEggStat> CriticalStats() {
  return StatsLessThan(-1.5);
}
```

Considering this, and the fact that upvoting or downvoting as the same effect regardless of the User stats real value, it doesn't matter which is done first.